# How can I stop this blinking effect?

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function that loops to create a blinking effect by replacing a button image.

```
function blinkit() {
   intrvl = 0;
   for (nTimes = 0; nTimes < 500; nTimes++)  {
      intrvl += 1000;
      t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('imgshowreport').src='report_icon.png';",intrvl);
      intrvl += 1000;
      t = setTimeout("document.getElementById('imgshowreport').src='report_icon2.png';",intrvl);
   }
}
```

This serves the purpose but when the button is clicked I want the blinking to stop. How can I do this without the whole page being refreshed?

Comment: @Kingpin: this does not help.

Comment: The problem with this question is that you're making assumptions about how to stop the blinking, the assumption being that you have to "stop a javascript loop". In fact, stopping the loop is useless to that entire part of your question is a red herring. Next time please describe your goal, not what you think the solution should be.

Comment: Your `function blinkit()` shortly finished without break: You generate 1000 setTimeout's. Last timeout finished after 500*1000 milliseconds (8 minutes and 20 seconds). Please, see answer of __Tomalak Geret'kal__ for implementation variant.

Answer (score 2):

Using `break` to terminate the loop is useless because your loop will already have concluded and set all the timeouts before the user can click the button.

It would be better to use `setInterval` once rather than queueing up hundreds of individual timeouts. Then you can kill the interval in one fell swoop.

You should also *not* use string code, but a function:

```
var myInterval = null;

function blinkit() {
  var i = 0;
  myInterval = setInterval(function() {
     document.getElementById('imgshowreport').src = (i % 2) ? 'report_icon2.png' : 'report_icon.png';
     i++;
  }, 1000);
}

document.getElementById('imgshowreport').onclick = function() {
   if (myInterval != null) {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
      myInterval = null;
      document.getElementById('imgshowreport').src = 'report_icon.png';
   }
};
```

I haven't tested it for typos, but the basic logic is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the break syntax

`break;`

or

```
nTimes = 500;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tell him _where_ to break. Your answer doesn't talk about button clicks at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try break
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: [Please do not propogate links to that site](http://www.w3fools.com) and this is not at all a complete or useful answer.

Comment: What's wrong with that site, and how is this not a useful answer, since it is "break" is the only elegant answer to this problem?

Comment: (a) Why don't you follow the link I provided which'll take you to a _large_ site listing all the reasons why? (b) Actually, `break` doesn't solve this at all.

Comment: He asked how to stop a loop. I assume he has the means to check WHEN to stop, and he was asking HOW. The link I provided was to some code example illustrating the use of the break; statement. It doesn't deal with certifications, trademark issues, etc.

Comment: Did you not bother to read the question body at all? What do trademarks have to do with it? The simple fact is that this answer does _not_ answer the question at hand.

Comment: I read the body, but I am not sure if that is his actual implementation or just an oversimplified example.

Comment: I'm sorry that you did not understand the question. See you soon. And hopefully you'll post answers in future that are [not just links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)!